# if a|b and a>0 then gcd(a,b)=a

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Is this proof right?

Prove: if a|b and a>0 then gcd(a,b)=a.

Let  a|b  and the  GCD(a,b) = m,  then  b=aq  for some integer  q  and the 
 GCD(a,b)  can be expressed as a linear combination with some integer  x  and  y,

```
       ax + by = m .
```

Substituting in b we get,

```
      ax + (aq)y = m
      a(x + qy) = m
```

But x + qy = GCD(1,q) =1.  Thus,

```
      a(1) = m
```

Hence a = GCD(a,b), which is what we needed to show.

Thanks for all the comments :)

Update 1:
I did not think I said that x and y were any integer I said that there was some integer x and some integer y so that ax +by = m 
Since I am supposing that the GCD(a,b) = m and a|b, then by substituting b into the GCD(a,b), then

```
      GCD(a,b)=GCD(a,aq)

              =a*GCD(1,q) Which is a property of GCD
```

But the GCD(1,q)=1. So, GCD(a,b) = a

Thanks for the comments :)

Comment: No, there is no reason for $x+qy=1$. Just because $\gcd(1,q)=1$ doesn't mean that *for all* x,y, you get $x+qy=1$. So you have to answer why it is $=1$.

Comment: sadly, things do not work like that. it's "there exists $x,y$", not "for all $x,y$".

Comment: Is $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ or just a random integer domain $R$? Why not just go by definition. It kinda follows immediatly.

Comment: I would not allow you to use GCD (a,aq)=aGCD (1,q) if you haven't proven GCD (a,b)=a if a|b first.  It's circular, as both require the same observations to prove.  Anyway, this is preposterous complicated for something that is essentially trivial: a divides b and a so it is a common divisor. Anything bigger than a can'can't divide a so it is the greatest common divisor.  That's it.

Answer (score 3):

$a|a $ and $a|b $ so $a $ is a common divisor of $a $ and $b $.

Anything bigger than $a$ cannot divide $a$.  So $a $ is the greatest common divisor.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

$a|b \Rightarrow b=aq$, for some integer $q$.

GCD means *greatest common divisor*.

If $ a\geq 1$, then what is the *largest* integer which divides both $a$ and $aq$?